# Access indices of variables with a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've defined these six points in a coordinate system:

```
P1 = (0,0)
P2 = (0,-2)
P3 = (4,-2)
P4 = (4,0)
P5 = (4,2)
P6 = (2,1)
```

Now, I'd like to make a list of all the x-coordinates with a `for` loop reading the indices.

Something like this:

```
[P[i+1][0] for i in range(6)]
```

to get the result `[0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0]`. How do I make Python read the `P[i+1]` as P1, P2, P3...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the points in a data structure that relates them to each other in some way so you can iterate over them. This can be done with a list as follows:

```py
points = [(0,0), (0,-2), (4,-2), (4,0), (4,2), (0,2)]
x_coords = [x for (x, y) in points]
print(x_coords)
```

Comment: Oh I see. Just tried it, doing this:

points = [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6]
x_coords = [x for (x, y) in points]
print(x_coords)

works as well :)

Comment: Oh, yes. That's perfectly fine. It's just important to store them somewhere that makes them relatable to each other. Of course, some data structures are more suited than others for a specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To use your P[i+1] indexing I would suggest a dict where the keys are indices in range `[1, 7)` and the values are your points.

```
# P = {1: (0,0), 2: (0,-2), 3: (4,-2) ...}
P = dict(zip(range(1,7), [(0,0), (0,-2), (4,-2), (4,0), (4,2), (0,2)]))

x_coord = [P[i+1][0] for i in range(6)]
print(x_coord)
```

However if you only want the x coordinate of each tuple you could go for something like this:

```
points = [(0,0), (0,-2), (4,-2), (4,0), (4,2), (0,2)]
x_coords = ...
print(x_coords)
```

You could go for either this:

```
x_coords = [x for x,_ in points]
```

or:

```
x_coords = list(map(lambda x:x[0], points))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want Python to

> read the P[i+1] as P1, P2, P3...

So, the main point is using f"P{i+1}" to produce P1, P2, .... Then, I suggest you use these as keys to a dictionary. This way, your code works even when the number of points is changed.

```
points = {'P1': (0,0), 'P2': (0,-2), 'P3': (4,-2), 'P4': (4,0), 'P5': (4,2), 'P6': (2,1)}
```

Assume the number of points is 6:

```
indices = range(1, 7)
```

Now you can have a list of X's:

```
Print([points[f"P{index}"][0] for index in indices])
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 2]
```